# How to drag and drop to DevExpress Schedule Control in versions before 19.2?

Tags: .net, winforms, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui, devexpress-gridcontrol

I have a Winforms app, C#, .Net Framework 4.6.1, DevExpress version 18.1.  I'm stuck with those versions.  I want to be able to drag and drop a row from a DevExpress GridView to a DevXpress ScheduleControl.  [This site](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/401989/controls-and-libraries/data-grid/drag-and-drop) shows how to do it, but apparently it's only for more recent versions.  I've searched for any documentation on older versions, but can't find anything; all the DevExpress comments seem to point back to that site.  Is it possible to drag and drop in older versions?  If so, how do I do that?  Is there any documentation?

Here's the page that shows exactly what I want to do:

[image]

The documentation says to use the event PrepareDragData, but there is no such event.  I tried to manually add the event and get an error.  I also tried other similar sounding events like DragOver, but it did not work.  There is also references to an object named AppointmentExchangeData that I don't know what it is or have a reference too.

[image]

Here's the PrepareDragData method from my code and the errors it shows.
[image]